# My ListView is showing the same item twice. How do I fix it?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, uwp

I have a `ComboBox` that allows the user to select a category and a `ListView` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of items in the selected category. When the user selects a different category, the items in the collection are updated. Sometimes this works as expected, but sometimes the list of items is mangled. **It shows a duplicate item when there should be two separate items.**

The results seem to depend on which category I'm switching from. For example, if I switch from a category with no items to a category with two items, the same item is shown twice. But if I switch from a category with four items to that same category with two items, they are shown correctly.

Here is a repro:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Groups}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Widgets}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedWidget, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Widget">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <local:MyControl
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedWidget.Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _selectedGroup;
        private Widget _selectedWidget;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PropertyChanged += HomeViewModel_PropertyChanged;
            SelectedGroup = Groups.First();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(DataSource.AllGroups);

        public string SelectedGroup
        {
            get => _selectedGroup;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedGroup != value)
                {
                    _selectedGroup = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedGroup)));
                }
            }
        }

        public Widget SelectedWidget
        {
            get => _selectedWidget;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedWidget != value)
                {
                    _selectedWidget = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedWidget)));
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Widget> Widgets { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Widget>();

        private void HomeViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedGroup))
            {
                var widgetsToLoad = DataSource.GetWidgetsForGroup(SelectedGroup);
                // Add widgets in this group
                widgetsToLoad.Except(Widgets).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Add(w));
                // Remove widgets not in this group
                Widgets.Except(widgetsToLoad).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Remove(w));
                // Select the first widget
                if (SelectedWidget == null && Widgets.Any())
                {
                    SelectedWidget = Widgets.First();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DataSource.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding
{
    public static class DataSource
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<string> AllGroups { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "First Widget",
            "First Two Widgets",
            "Last Two Widgets",
            "All Widgets",
            "None"
        };

        public static List<Widget> AllWidgets { get; } = new List<Widget>
        {
            new Widget()
            {
                Id = 1,
            },
            new Widget()
            {
                Id = 2,
            },
            new Widget()
            {
                Id = 3,
            },
            new Widget()
            {
                Id = 4,
            }
        };

        public static List<Widget> GetWidgetsForGroup(string group)
        {
            switch (group)
            {
                case "First Widget":
                    return new List<Widget> { AllWidgets[0] };

                case "First Two Widgets":
                    return new List<Widget> { AllWidgets[0], AllWidgets[1] };

                case "Last Two Widgets":
                    return new List<Widget> { AllWidgets[2], AllWidgets[3] };

                case "All Widgets":
                    return new List<Widget>(AllWidgets);

                default:
                    return new List<Widget>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Widget.cs**

```
namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding
{
    public class Widget
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Binding
{
    public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MyControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my project to use [{x:Bind} (compiled bindings)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) appeared to resolve the issue, but a week later I unexpectedly started seeing duplicate items in my `ListView` again. This time I discovered three other factors that contributed to this issue.

1. I added a `FallbackValue` to the `TextBoxes` bound to the `SelectedItem` so they would be cleared when no item was selected. If I remove the `FallbackValue`, the list items are not duplicated. However, I need this setting.
2. I discovered that the order in which I add and remove items with the `ObservableCollection` bound to the `ListView` is important. If I add new items first and then remove old items, list items are duplicated. If I remove old items first and then add new items, the items are not duplicated. However, I'm using `AutoMapper.Collection` to update this collection, so I have no control over the order.
3. A colleague suggested that this bug may be related to the `ListView.SelectedItem`. I discovered that if I set the selected item to `null` before removing it from the collection, list items are not duplicated. This is the solution I am now using.

Here's an example:

```
    // This resolves the issue:
    if (!widgetsToLoad.Contains(SelectedWidget))
    {
        SelectedWidget = null;
    }

    // AutoMapper.Collection updates collections in this order. The issue does not occur
    // if the order of these two lines of code is reversed.
    {
        // Add widgets in this group
        widgetsToLoad.Except(Widgets).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Add(w));
        // Remove widgets not in this group
        Widgets.Except(widgetsToLoad).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Remove(w));
    }
```

For a full repro, replace the code blocks in the question with these changes:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewDuplicateItem_Fallback.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ListViewDuplicateItem_Fallback">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Groups}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedGroup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Widgets}"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedWidget, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Widget">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Id}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedWidget.Id, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue=''}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Fallback
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _selectedGroup;
        private Widget _selectedWidget;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PropertyChanged += HomeViewModel_PropertyChanged;
            SelectedGroup = Groups.First();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(DataSource.AllGroups);

        public string SelectedGroup
        {
            get => _selectedGroup;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedGroup != value)
                {
                    _selectedGroup = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedGroup)));
                }
            }
        }

        public Widget SelectedWidget
        {
            get => _selectedWidget;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedWidget != value)
                {
                    _selectedWidget = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedWidget)));
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Widget> Widgets { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Widget>();

        private void HomeViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedGroup))
            {
                var widgetsToLoad = DataSource.GetWidgetsForGroup(SelectedGroup);

                // This resolves the issue:
                //if (!widgetsToLoad.Contains(SelectedWidget))
                //{
                //    SelectedWidget = null;
                //}

                // AutoMapper.Collection updates collections in this order. The issue does not occur
                // if the order of these two lines of code is reversed. I do not simply clear the
                // collection and reload it because this clears the selected item even when it is in
                // both groups, and the animation is much smoother if items are not removed and reloaded.
                {
                    // Add widgets in this group
                    widgetsToLoad.Except(Widgets).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Add(w));
                    // Remove widgets not in this group
                    Widgets.Except(widgetsToLoad).ToList().ForEach(w => Widgets.Remove(w));
                }

                // Select the first widget
                if (SelectedWidget == null && Widgets.Any())
                {
                    SelectedWidget = Widgets.First();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DataSource.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ListViewDuplicateItem_Fallback
{
    public static class DataSource
    {
        public static List<string> AllGroups { get; set; } = new List<string> { "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3" };

        public static List<Widget> AllWidgets { get; set; } = new List<Widget>(Enumerable.Range(1, 11).Select(widgetId => new Widget { Id = widgetId }));

        public static List<Widget> GetWidgetsForGroup(string group)
        {
            switch (group)
            {
                case "Group 1":
                    return AllWidgets.Take(4).ToList();

                case "Group 2":
                    return AllWidgets.Skip(4).Take(4).ToList();

                case "Group 3":
                    return AllWidgets.Take(1).Union(AllWidgets.Skip(8).Take(3)).ToList();

                default:
                    return new List<Widget>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only seems to occur when the project includes a custom control that uses the Binding markup.

In the example above, if `MyControl` is removed from `MainPage.xaml`, it works as expected.

Likewise, if `<local:MyControl Text="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedWidget.Id}" />` is changed to `<local:MyControl Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedWidget.Id}" />`, the example works as expected

This appears to be a bug in the `ListView` control, but you can work around it by using [{x:Bind} compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension).

*Edit: Upon further investigation, the custom control may have been a red herring. Changing the custom control to a standard TextBox does not resolve the issue as I previously thought. The issue can be reproduced without the custom control. Nonetheless, using {x:Bind} or removing the control entirely does resolve the issue in this case.*